# How to create tableviwer and treeviwer in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I am new in SWT.

I need help with building UI.
The UI should look be with three parts :

1. First big header
2. left side -tree viwer with 3 action on the toolbar
3. right side table viewer with header and action bar

The left part and in the right part should be with border.

I tried to read on the layout in SWT but it was very hard to understand it.

Maybe do you have any example for the UI ? maybe just for the layout of the UI

[image]

Comment: This is a Q&A site don't expect us to write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something which is easy to use then WindowBuilder is your friend. I suggest you should use Eclipse (since WB is an Eclipse plugin).

It will help you tremendously.